# Yii2 controlling Nginx (like "named restart", "nginx restart", etc)

Tags: nginx, yii2, rabbitmq

I`m looking for some control ability to manage my Nginx server from web-site bassed on Yii2( or native PHP).

What's the best practice to manage Nginx using Yii2? Could I use Rabbitmg?

For example, I need to restart nginx (/etc/init.d/nginx restart) after some action happens.

Answer (score 0):

[Yii Installation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#recommended-nginx-configuration) and You need to restart the nginx service on every action done in nginx configurations.

Comment: So, how can I call restarting the Nginx service on every action?